Telerik Angular kendo-angular-notification does not goes on new line
I have a problem with Telerik kendo-angular-notification, when I try to show a failing validation of the model it doesn't go to a new line. I've tried to use <br/>  , \n\r, \n but it does not seems to work
Here's the snippet of code I'm using
save() {
    this.busy.next(true);
    this.guideConfigurationService.updateGuideConfi(this.globalGuideSettings).subscribe(_ => {
      this.toastService.success("guide Configuration Saved successfully");
      this.busy.next(false);
    }, error => {
      let errorString: string = "Error while saving the Configuration.";
      Object.keys(error.error.errors).forEach((key) => {
        error.error.errors[key].forEach((error: any) => {
          errorString += `Key: ${key}, Error: ${error}\n\r`;
        });
      });
      this.toastService.error(errorString, 0);
      this.busy.next(false);
      return;
    })
  }

I'm generating the validation error message via .NET FluentValidation.
The result is the following.
I'm using Angular 16 and Telerik components version 14.

